# Don't know why GPUImageFilterGroup use flipped frame buffer when drawing the filter in even position

Tags: android-gpuimageview

Following is the **onDraw** method in **GPUImageFilterGroup.java**.

```
// GPUImageFilterGroup.java
public void onDraw(final int textureId, final FloatBuffer cubeBuffer,
                   final FloatBuffer textureBuffer) {
    runPendingOnDrawTasks();
    if (!isInitialized() || mFrameBuffers == null || mFrameBufferTextures == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mMergedFilters != null) {
        int size = mMergedFilters.size();
        int previousTexture = textureId;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            GPUImageFilter filter = mMergedFilters.get(i);
            boolean isNotLast = i < size - 1;
            if (isNotLast) {
                GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFrameBuffers[i]);
                GLES20.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            if (i == 0) {
                filter.onDraw(previousTexture, cubeBuffer, textureBuffer);
            } else if (i == size - 1) {
                filter.onDraw(previousTexture, mGLCubeBuffer, (size % 2 == 0) ? mGLTextureFlipBuffer : mGLTextureBuffer);
            } else {
                filter.onDraw(previousTexture, mGLCubeBuffer, mGLTextureBuffer);
            }

            if (isNotLast) {
                GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
                previousTexture = mFrameBufferTextures[i];
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**mGLTextureBuffer** stores the positions of the texture.

```
public static final float TEXTURE_NO_ROTATION[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

**mGLTextureFlipBuffer** is the upside-down of **mGLTextureBuffer** in vertical direction.

Just can't figure out why **even filter** and **odd filter** use different buffer as following line?

```
else if (i == size - 1)
    filter.onDraw(previousTexture, mGLCubeBuffer, (size % 2 == 0) ? mGLTextureFlipBuffer : mGLTextureBuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `GPUImage.setupCamera()`, you will pass `flipHorizontal` and `flipVertical`. So, if you applied even (or odd) number of filters, the texture will be flipped even(or odd) times. If you don't like this, modify this as I do:

```
    if (i == size - 1) {// the last filter
      filter.onDraw(previousTexture, mGLCubeBuffer, textureBuffer);
    } else {
    //normalTextureBuffer is the not-clipped version of textureBuffer
      filter.onDraw(previousTexture, mGLCubeBuffer, normalTextureBuffer);
    }
```

Using the code above, you will get a 90-degree-rotated texture whenever you add one filter to the group, thus 4 filters for a 360-degree-rotated(same rotation as the input texture) texture. `mGLCubeBuffer` and `textureBuffer` have different rotations differing 90 degrees.
May this help.